# How to solve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: java, android, webview

[Error & Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfUiO.jpg)

My codes and error are in that link of picture "Error & Codes"

Hi everyone, you all doing well,

Im having a problem about WebView, i have tried many ways but I'm still getting this err_connection_refuse error and i cant solve it. Can anyone see what my problem is ?

I'm trying to use this way to show the world map in that web address on my phone but if there are any suggestion, I'm open to it.

(Android Studio 4.0 + Java + API 28 + Blacked URL address due to company policy )

Thank you :)

IMPORTANT NOTE :

That site can only be reached with VPN (i can reach it from web browser on computer) but i have installed cisco anyconnect VPN to emulator and secured connection too.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that the server you are trying to contact is not picking up the connection request; it's more likely an error with the server than with your app code. Are you sure you spelled the web host correctly? Are you sure the web server is running on the correct port?

Comment: yes sir spelled correcty andserver is running perfectly and i can reach it from my computer through vpn

Comment: vpn works differently on pc & emulator, soo its useless to  do that with connected vpn

Comment: if you want to be sure, just connect up with vpn & open chrome in emulator & try open your link, it wont open there as well

Comment: @Blu you are correct!  its not working in chrome too. So what should i do to test it on emulator is there any way ?

Comment: if your url needs vpn to get accessed, idk any solution for it soo far to open it on emulator, its kind of not possible thing

Comment: okay, thank you so much

Comment: Seems like a CORS issue. Your server at 10.* is probably not allowed to be loaded across domains. Also it's a class A private ip, so check if your mobile environment/emulator is connected to the same subnet. Maybe try hitting that IP from a browser in that mobile/emulator

Comment: @KoustavRay thanks  i will check